# Cannot overwrite a value option for a f.check_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

This is pretty silly but I cant change the value attribute of a check_box, the line is like this:

`= f.check_box :scan, :style => 'margin-right: 40px', :value => 'MBL'`

it builds the tag showing value = "1"

help please!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= f.check_box :scan, {style: 'margin-right: 40px'}, 'MBL'
```

[Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box)

Comment: Wherever you are send you a big hug!!!!!!!!!!!!! thanks a lot, Im new in ruby on rails and haml Thanks a lot for the link too!!! :) :)

Comment: I think that in HAML I'm even newer - I have never used this yet. :)
Your welcome. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can provide checked value and unchecked value in this helper as following.

```
= f.check_box :scan,{style: 'margin-right: 40px'},"MBL","NMBL"
```

- If used like above, rails will generate hidden field having same name attribute with value 'NMBL' otherwise default value is 0 for unchecked.
- When form is submitted, value is sent as 'MBL' or 'NMBL' for checked or unchecked respectively. I hope you find this useful.